# If else based on existence of python function optional arguments

Tags: python, arguments

I have written a function as follows, with optional argument 'b'.

url depends on the existence of b.

```
def something(a, b=None)
    if len(b) >= 1:
        url = 'http://www.xyz.com/%sand%s' % (a, b)
    else:
        url = 'http://www.xyz.com/%s' (a)
```

This raises an error when `b=None`, saying *"object of type 'none-type' has no length"*

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: What should happen if `b` is `""`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can simply use `if b:` - this will require the value to be both not `None` and not an empty string/list/whatever.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply change -

```
def something(a, b=None)
```

to -

```
def something(a, b="")
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless you really need to check the length of `b`, why not simply do

```
if b is not None:
    ...
```

If you also need to check the length (so the `else` part is executed also if `b == ""`), use

```
if b is not None and len(b) >= 1:
    ...
```

The `and` operator short-circuits, meaning that if `b is None`, the second part of the expression is not even evaluated, so no exception will be raised.

Answer (score 4):

To evaluate the length of `b` when it's not `None`, change the `if` statement to:

```
if b is not None and len(b) >= 1:
   ...
```

Because of the `and` operator, `len(b)` will not be evaluated if the first test (`b is not None`) fails. Ie the expression evaluation is short-circuited.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
def something(a, *b):
    if len(b) == 0:
        print('Equivalent to calling: something(a)')
    else:
        print('Both a and b variables are present')
```